# Perl - Get sum of items using a unique key [group]

Tags: perl, grouping

For example

From this:

> UserA|Single|Girly|200|500
>   UserA|Single|Boyish|200|200
>   UserA|Double|Girly|100|200
>   UserA|Multiple|Boyish|200|400
>   UserA|Double|Girly|250|150
>   UserA|Single|Boyish|150|150

To this:

> UserA|Single|Girly|200|500
>   UserA|Single|Boyish|350|350
>   UserA|Double|Girly|350|350
>   UserA|Multiple|Boyish|200|400

How should I code this in order to get the sum of the line by their same keys.
You get the basic idea from my example.

Thanks!

Comment: Create 2 hashes to store the sums, using a key of the concatenation of the first few fields.  `$total_1{ 'UserA|Single|Boyish'} += $value_1;`  Then just iterate over the keys of both hashes to produce the totals.

Comment: The next time you post a question, if you don't want to get down voted, please try to do something and post the code which you worked on. Also, accept the answer to your question if it matches your question requirements.

Comment: I just forgot to update this thread. I already solved my problem, I just made a unique key to group the user with their status so I can append the previous value to the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
while(my $line = <DATA>)
{
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /(.*\|.*\|.*)\|(\d*)\|(\d*)/)
    {
        # you want to group them by the first 3 attributes, therefore:
        # 1 will hold UserA|Single|Girly
        # 2 will hold the first value
        # 3 will hold the second value
        $hash{$1}{'first_value'} += $2;
        $hash{$1}{'second_value'} += $3;
    }
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper %hash;


__DATA__
UserA|Single|Girly|200|500
UserA|Single|Boyish|200|200
UserA|Double|Girly|100|200
UserA|Multiple|Boyish|200|400
UserA|Double|Girly|250|150
UserA|Single|Boyish|150|150
```

The result looks like this :

```
$VAR1 = 'UserA|Multiple|Boyish';
$VAR2 = {
          'first' => '200',
          'second' => '400'
        };
$VAR3 = 'UserA|Double|Girly';
$VAR4 = {
          'first' => '350',
          'second' => '350'
        };
$VAR5 = 'UserA|Single|Boyish';
$VAR6 = {
          'first' => '350',
          'second' => '350'
        };
$VAR7 = 'UserA|Single|Girly';
$VAR8 = {
          'first' => '200',
          'second' => '500'
        };
```